# Page content hard to read under phone's clock on React Native for iOS

Tags: react-native

I have padding at the top of my screen so the page title sits below the phone's time, battery info etc:

[image]

However when you scroll the page content is shown under the time making it hard to read:

[image]

What is the solution to this? I tried using `SafeAreaView` but it didn't seem to make a difference:

```
return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled style={styles.container1}>
      <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container2}>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Title</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container1: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: "rgb(0, 230, 164);",
      flexDirection: "column"
    },
    container2: {
      flex: 1,
      paddingTop: 60,
      paddingBottom: 40,
      paddingHorizontal: 10
    },
    heading: {
      fontSize: 20,
      textTransform: "uppercase",
      textAlign: "center",
      marginBottom: "10%"
    },
  });
```

It's only in issue on iOS, Android seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem, try this code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text,TextInput,Alert,KeyboardAvoidingView,StyleSheet,ScrollView,SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

export default class  App extends Component{ 
  constructor(props) 
  {
      super(props);
  }
render()
    {
return (
     <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled style={styles.container1}>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container2}>
      <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Title</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text><Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text><Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>
          <Text>Text</Text>

          </ScrollView>
          </SafeAreaView>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>

  );
}

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container1: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: "rgb(0, 230, 164);",
      flexDirection: "column"
    },
    container2: {
      flex: 1,
      paddingTop: 60,
      paddingBottom: 40,
      paddingHorizontal: 10
    },
    heading: {
      fontSize: 20,
      textTransform: "uppercase",
      textAlign: "center",
      marginBottom: "10%"
    },
  });
```

Here is the link for expo (code running perfectly for both iOS and android)
https://snack.expo.io/@asad_4561/textinput?session_id=snack-session-7_eZSvZUo&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=33hlricz7f&supportedPlatforms=ios,android,web&name=TextInput&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true

Comment: try this code, it's work for both devices (android and iOS).

Comment: Basically SafeAreaView works as a container that respect the visual limits of the notification tools and notches.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 : you can hide status bar

import StatusBar from react-native and add this line in render method inside first Component use this for onescreen only,

```
<StatusBar hidden />
```

if you want it for entire app,
in App.js import StatusBar and out side of any class add this,

```
StatusBar.setHidden(true);
```

Option 2 : use translucent property screenwise, this is by default false but just try if it works.

```
<StatusBar hidden  translucent={false}/>
```

for entire App,
in App.js import StatusBar and out side of any class add this,

```
StatusBar.setTranslucent(false);
```